# How to stop application from being suspended by Ctrl+z?

Tags: suspend, dtach

Currently I'm running `dvtm` inside a terminal, and `vim` inside `dvtm`. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> intending to suspend `vim`, `dvtm` got suspended instead. I didn't have this problem with `screen` or `tmux`, so I think it must be `dvtm` doing something wrong (or not doing something right). How can I fix that?

Update: I was wrong, this is not a problem with `dvtm`. Indeed I was using the `dtach`+`dvtm` combo and wrongly assumed that dvtm was at fault. The problem is really with `dtach`.

Comment: I've just tried on Debian lenny (dvtm 0.4.1) and Ubuntu 10.04 (dvtm 0.5.2), and the behavior is the expected one (`Ctrl+Z` suspends vim).

Comment: @Gilles You are right, `dvtm` is not the problem. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update** (new answer):

`dtach` has a `-z` option with the description "Disable processing of the suspend key".  Confusing if you ask me, but its effect seems to be that the <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> is passed through to Vim instead of being caught by `dtach`.

More general answer: a program like `dtach` or `dvtm` has pretty much absolute control over what gets passed through to whatever's running "inside" of it.  It's like having a secretary take dictation -- you can say what you like, but the secretary controls what actually appears on the paper.  So if you want the end program to receive the Ctrl+Z, you have to get all of the middle layers to cooperate, whether that be through command line options or source code editing.

---

<strike>Looks to me like this is a bug in `dvtm`.  From inspection of the source code, it's not catching the `SIGTSTP` signal, which is what is sent to your terminal's foreground application when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.  Since it's not catching the signal explicitly, it falls back on default behavior and gets suspended.  What `dvtm` needs to do is catch this signal and pass it along to one of its windows.</strike>

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but sorry it was my mistake. `dtach` is the one responsible for this, not `dvtm`.

Comment: @Gilles: You're right, and on further inspection, `dvtm` does what you've described.  And now that I've actually tried it instead of just assuming things and poking around in the source, I'm seeing the correct behavior as well.